# In a triangle ABC, a point D such that BDC, and BD = AD= AC. Show that AB>AC

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to prove that in such triangle, AB>AC, but I can't suceed. I tried to use some properties of isósceles triangle since the sides are equal, but couldn't find something nice. Also, whats the criteria needed to prove that a side in a triangle is greater than the other? Thank you so much!

Comment: "a point D such that BDC" ... what does this mean?  Point D lies on BC?

Comment: @John yes, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

(the diagram is not meant to be to scale)

$$\angle BAD\stackrel{\text{isosc}}=\angle B:=a$$
$$\angle ADC\stackrel{\text{isosc}}=\angle C\stackrel{(1)}=2a$$
$\angle C>\angle B\implies AB>AC$. For a proof of this, see [this](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/java/elements/bookI/propI18.html) and then [this](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/java/elements/bookI/propI19.html).

$(1)$: triangle angles add up to $180^{\circ}$.
[image]

Comment: I understood affirmations 1 and 2, and I also know that the side opposite to the greater angle is greater, but I don't understand how it proves that AB>AC. Do I need to prove that AB is the greater side of the triangle, or better: 2a is the greater angle?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs You said: "the side opposite to the greater angle is greater". $\angle C>\angle B$ (because $2a>a$), and since $AB$ is opposite to $\angle C$ and $AC$ is opposite to $\angle B$, we have $AB>AC$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $|AC|=|AD|, \triangle ACD$ is isosceles and $\angle ADB$ is obtuse.

[image]

Therefore $|AB| > |BD| = |AC|$